# UWP - What is the best arrangement for multiple views? Windowing or navigation?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm developing an app for simulating electric/electronic circuits for Win 10 (Desktop), and publish to the Microsoft Store.

I need to show multiple views in this app. There is a view of the design/circuit schematic, and there are other views for inspecting the circuit response.

With the navigation paradigm (which I think was proposed for UWP) The user would edit the design in the design view, then navigate to the circuit response view, and inspect the numbers/curves, then navigate back to the circuit, and keep editing. This back and forth navigation can be annoying.

Much better could it be to allow see the two views in the screen simultaneously. (Like MDI, but those views/windows would not be separate "documents", instead of that, they are different aspects related to the same design user is working on.)
This could allow to perform operations in one view/window and see how the changes made by user impacts on other views in real time.
Also is desired to allow the user to put any view on full screen if desired. Circuit or Response curves.

Pretty much like this very old piece of software:

[image: MDI WINDOWS]

Here I found a video of an example of multiple views in UWP
[Multiple views in UWP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2PijMLk2sk)

The third and last, option, what I think is the BEST, would be to use a window docking manager, like the one used in VisualStudio. This gives the user very much freedom of how to arrange the views/windows. AvalonDock is a beautiful example, but it is for WPF, not UWP.

So, guys, I ask for your opinion, What is the best approach for multiple views arrangement for this UWP app?, What should I do? What solution would you take? Why?

Personally, I think a windows docking system is by far the best. But I do not find a library for that. There is the SyncFusion Docking manager, but their UWPControl package is very expensive. 995 U$D, too much for my budget...

Regards

Comment: I'm just curious how did you mange the wire ? a path with each point ?

Comment: i have an abstract class called ElectricElement, it has a collection of Terminals, and two subclasses of ElectricElement: Wire and Component, 
A wire object has only two terminals, and those can be bounded (slave) to terminals of others ElectricElements, or be free. so therefore a Wire can be attached to any terminal of a component, or to other wire. a Wire does know the element and terminal it is bounding (of any of its two terminals), also the elements mantain a list of attached wires for each terminal (handled with events)

Comment: for building up the electric nodes, I traverse the graph using a recursive, feedbacking algorithm.. each eletric node has a list of tuples<Component,terminalNumber>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display to `Pages` simulatenously, you can achieve it by using two `Frame` controls. `Frame` control acts as a "navigation target`and manages a stack of pages. By default every UWP app has a single root frame, but you can override this by having a root *shell* page, which will contain the global navigation - top menu, and two`Frames`.

Multiple views is also possible and is used by apps like Paint 3D. Unfortunately, it is a bit harder to communicate among views, as each has its own UI thread, so cross-view data-binding is quite complex.

Of course, the mentioned docking pattern would be even more suitable for your case.

The free solution might be possible using two controls from the **Windows Community Toolkit**: [`DockPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/dockpanel) and [`GridSplitter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/gridsplitter). But it would be up to you to implement the drag and drop functionality for your panels.

As for Syncfusion, there might be a chance to get the toolkit for free - see the [Syncfusion Community Edition](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense). This is a free version of the whole range of their controls and as per FAQ it is eligible for:

> Companies and individuals with less than $1 million USD in annual gross revenue and 5 or fewer developers.

Finally, another option would be to implement the app as a WPF app, which you will then light-up with [.NET Core 3.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/) and [XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls) which should be released soon as a first preview.

Answer (score 2):

I'd lean toward a two-pane view, using a vertical splitter control, with the circuit on the left and the response curves on the right. That will be easy to implement, and easy to explain to users.

If you find yourself wanting multiple response views as the app matures, consider using a tab control on the right pane, or give the user the option of adding more panes, with splitters to adjust pane sizes.

I'm working on an app right now for which the entire window (except for a toolbar and tree control on the left edge) is a horizontal scrolling region which contains a horizontal stack-panel of views. When users open more views (by picking from the tree control), the new views just get appended to the left side of the stack panel. Users can scroll the stack panel left and right to navigate between views.

I can't really promise this will work well because I haven't released it to any users yet, but I'm using it myself and so far I like the way it works.

Comment: That is a good idea about a simple UI, but effective, and easy to understand. I will consider it. Thanks for sharing your opinion. What you did sounds like the BladeView control in the Windows Community Toolkit. Regards